# Custom native blackberry calendar event

Tags: blackberry, calendar

How can I create a custom event on the native blackberry calendar which I can read, write and modify. I am able to add a custom menu field on the calendar but from there I want to add a custom event on the calendar with custom fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EventList eventList = (EventList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.WRITE_ONLY);
_event = eventList.createEvent();
_event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE,"Event Name");
_event.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, "Event Date in long format");
RepeatRule rule = new RepeatRule();
rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.YEARLY);// There is many options in RepeatRule like Daily,Weakly,Monthly,Yearly, ect...
_event.setRepeat(rule);
_event.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , except the fields available in the Event class, can I add I my own fields . Like e.g. a meeting location field or a drop down to select among some options, like a fully customized event with only the details I want.

Comment: Yes you can do this with your own "Menu".

Comment: Sir I want to create a custom Event, as you have explained I get how to achieve menu customization, but what I am looking for is a custom event that I can add to the native calendar.